# MSSQL server not configuring in codeigniter. i.e. not establishing a connection

Tags: php, sql-server, database, codeigniter, sqlsrv

I have problems regarding making connection in codeigniter with database. I have tried a lot and have tested many solutions given by different persons but didn't succeeded so far.

My configuration in codeigniter are:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'DX-PC\MSSQLSERVER';
//$db['default']['port'] = 1433;
$db['default']['username'] = 'myusername';
$db['default']['password'] = 'mypass';
$db['default']['database'] = 'mydbname';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE; //default: TRUE
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

So, it gives me below error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>   Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Similarly, i have tried the connection establishment with the MS SQL server without using the codeigniter by using the below code:

```
    echo 'called';

    echo "<br>";

    $serverName = "DX-PC\\MSSQLSERVER"; //serverName\instanceName
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"mydbname", "UID"=>"myusername", "PWD"=>"mypass");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName,$connectionInfo);
    if( $conn ) {
        echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }else{
        echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r(sqlsrv_errors());
        echo "</pre>";
    }
```

It gave me these errors:

```
called Connection could not be established.

Array
  (
    [0] => Array
       (
        [0] => 08001
        [SQLSTATE] => 08001
        [1] => 87
        [code] => 87
        [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87]. 
        [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87]. 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => HYT00
        [SQLSTATE] => HYT00
        [1] => 0
        [code] => 0
        [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
        [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 08001
        [SQLSTATE] => 08001
        [1] => 87
        [code] => 87
        [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
        [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
    )
```

)

I have tried every solution from different forums and stackoverflow but didn't succeeded. Kindly help me. Thanks

Comment: In .htaccess file , check or correct your url:  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /yourRootFolder/index.php?/$1 [L]`

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /cheddargetter/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cheddargetter/index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>               i have changed it. still getting db error

Answer (score 0):

In the past I had also problems, so I did it the classic way:

```
$server = "x.x.x.x\MSSQL2005,1435";
$user = "xxxx";
$pass = "xxxx";

$this->ms  = mssql_connect($server, $user, $pass) or die ("No connection");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i have figured it out and it's working now.
The following changes make it working.

1. Previous configuration as you must have done, previously. i.e. (extensions: sqlsrv_*.dll etc adding in php.ini etc)
2. Change the rewrite rule in .htaccess from RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L] to RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /yourrootfolder/index.php?/$1 [L]    (Courtesy SHAZ)
3. Secondly, as i have a default instance named MSSQLSERVER so it doesn't need to write $db['default']['hostname'] = 'DX-PC\MSSQLSERVER'; but instead WROTE $db['default']['hostname'] = 'DX-PC';

I hope this can help others. Thanks.